# Create a task on a lightning web component without apex only javascript controller?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

My  question is on a salesforce topic.
I need to create a new task when a button is clicked in a lightning web component, and i sort of need it to be done only in javascript. Can anybody help me with the function for the button please?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started_supported_objects.htm), Task object is not yet supported.

This means that currently you will not be able to use [createRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_create_record) method to create your record from the javascript side.

You don't have the choice to use Apex for this I'm afraid.